# how to compare two audio signals

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I have two audio signal that I want to compare using Matlab, my problem is that I can hear the difference between both loud and clear, but when use the function `pwelch` to compare their PSD ,I don't see much difference between them,any idea how can I compare them with a different methode ! thanks in advance !

Comment: Why/What for do you want to compare them? Which are the lengths for each signals? Can you plot them and put the figures here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298644/how-to-compare-two-audio-signals-with-matlab?noredirect=1#comment33884548_22298644